# Python Pandas - Column - All possible combination

Tags: python, pandas, combinations

I have a dataset with 2 columns (`Name` and `Score`) and I would like to split the column `Name` in 2 groups: `group 1` and `group 2`. Then, I will have to  calculate `sum(score group 1) / sum(score group 2)`. My goal is to find in all combinations of names and groups, what is the smallest `sum(score group 1) / sum(score group 2)`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': list('ABCDEF'),
    'Score': [600, 1000, 300, 100, -100, 3000],
}, columns=['Name', 'Score'])

df

  Name  Score
0    A    600
1    B   1000
2    C    300
3    D    100
4    E   -100
5    F   3000
```

Example of first interaction:

```
   Group  Name  Score
0  1      A     600
1  2      B     1000
2  2      C     300
3  2      D     100
4  2      E     -100
5  2      F     3000
```

`sum(score group 1) / sum(score group 2)` = 0.1395

Example of second interaction:

```
   Group  Name  Score
0  1      A     600
1  1      B     1000
2  2      C     300
3  2      D     100
4  2      E     -100
5  2      F     3000
```

`sum(score group 1) / sum(score group 2)` = 0.4848

And then, calculate score for all combinations and get the smallest `sum(score group 1) / sum(score group 2)`

Comment: smallest is -100 / (sum of all others). Is that what you need?

Comment: I'm confused and I do not understand what you want.  Can you please provide what your expectations are given the input you've already provided?

Comment: both groups should contains how many rows ? I mean is there a max or min number ?

Comment: @gabriel please put any example output as an [edit] - comments really don't work well for it...

Comment: Equal number in each group? Or can group1 had one value and 5 in the other group?

Comment: I edited adding some examples. It might help clarifying the output.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated my solution so it is in line with your examples.

Essentially, all possible combinations of your groups can be generated from the binary representation of all the numbers in the range `1` to `2**(len(df.index)) - 1`.

You then convert these binary representations to a list of bools (`comb_bools`) to allow them to be passed to your dataframe - group1 is represented by `comb_bools` and group2 by `not(comb_bools)`.

Once you have these lists you can easily calculate the value your require and store them in the list `result`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': list('ABCDEF'),
                   'Score': [600, 1000, 300, 100, -100, 3000],}, 
                   columns=['Name', 'Score'])

nb_combs = 2**len(df.index) - 1
group1 = []
group2 = []
result = []

for i in range(1, nb_combs):
    comb = list(map(int, list(format(i, '0' + str(len(df.index)) + 'b'))))
    comb_bools = list(map(bool, comb))

    group1.append(df[comb_bools]['Name'].values)
    group2.append(df[[not(j) for j in comb_bools]]['Name'].values)

    numerator = sum(df[df['Name'].isin(group1[i - 1])]['Score'].values)
    denominator = sum(df[df['Name'].isin(group2[i - 1])]['Score'].values)

    result.append(numerator / denominator)

min_idx = np.argmin(result)
print('Minimum value: {}'.format(result[min_idx]))
print('Corresponding Group1: {}'.format(group1[min_idx]))
print('Corresponding Group2: {}\n'.format(group2[min_idx]))
```

Output:

```
Minimum value: -50.0
Corresponding Group1: ['A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'F']
Corresponding Group2: ['E']
```